# Problem with taking the xth root of both sides.

Tags: abstract-algebra, arithmetic, roots

An equation like $x^x = 2$, I can see why it's tempting to take the xth root of both sides. But isn't there a major problem with that?

You are supposed to take the +/- root if the root is an even number. But how do you know if x is even? (It might not even be rational.)

How are you supposed to know if the root should be the principal root or the +/- root.

I am coming directly from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WWyMRmV1hLg), by the way.

Comment: If you are working with complex numbers, it is much more than simply "*taking the $\pm$ root.*"  In the event that you take an $n$'th root (*where $n$ is a positive integer*), there are in fact $n$ different possible roots.  That being said... when the exponent is not an integer it gets messy and when $x$ is both in the base *and* in the exponent... things get incredibly messy.  The actual solution to this problem will involve the [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), a non-elementary function which most normal people never have any reason to know about.

Comment: It's tempting, but it doesn't really simplify the problem: you would get $x=2^{1/x}$. As for roots: no, **the** root function is a function, so it doesn't take positive an negative values; the answer is always the nonnegative number that works in that situation. And for arbitrary exponent, the definition is that for $a\gt 0$, we have $a^b = e^{b\ln(a)}$. So the "$x$th root" would be $a^{1/x} = e^{\frac{1}{x}\ln(a)}$.

Comment: One direction to think about is to take logs, getting $x \ln x = \ln 2$...

Comment: @ArturoMagidin It's just the first step, as you can see in the video, it leads to the solution involving the Lambert W function. As for roots, ofc it's a function and it alone always takes the principal root. That is why you are supposed to put a +/- in front of certain roots when you take them, to show there are two possibilities there.

Comment: @gt6989b He does eventually do logs to solve the problem. I'm not focusing on that because I'm not trying to solve the equation. This question is just about why or why not you should put a +/- in front of xth root radicals.

Comment: @DrZ214: No, you don't put a $\pm$ if you are applying a function. That's an incorrect thing that people get taught in high school, often because they forget that you need to take absolute values when you compose roots with powers: $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$, not $\pm x$.  You aren't supposed to "put a +/- in front of certain roots when you take them." You are supposed to do the algebra correctly in the first place.